# No handler found for a given payload

Tags: spring-kafka

I get the following error on the consumer side :

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class xxx.web.json.customer.ContractRequestDto
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.getHandlerForPayload(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:170)
```

I  don't see what's the problem. The received type matches the type of the handler. The mapping would be possible...

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${kafka.groups.customer.name}")
    private String customerGroup;

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> containerFactory() {    
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Object>(getConsumerFactoryProperties()));        
        factory.setConcurrency(5);
        return factory;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getConsumerFactoryProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, customerGroup);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return props;
    }

}
```

And the listener:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Transactional
@KafkaListener(containerFactory = "containerFactory", topics = { "myTopic" })
public class ContractListeners {    


    @KafkaHandler
    public void init(ConsumerRecord<String, ContractRequestDto> record, @Payload ContractRequestDto object) {
        ...
    }       


}
```

My args are annotated with @Payload so according to the doc, it should work.
Do you have an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to look at the code to see if we support getting the full `ConsumerRecord` as well as its `value()` (payload).

But, I am not sure why you would want to do that, given that it's redundant in that you already have access to it via `record.value()`.

**EDIT**

I just wrote a test app and it works fine for me; so something else is going on; maybe your DTO is in a different package?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So59970536Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59970536Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so59970536").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, Foo> template) {
        return args -> template.send("so59970536", new Foo("bar"));
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private String bar;

        public Foo() {
        }

        public Foo(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}

@Component
@KafkaListener(id = "so59970536", topics = "so59970536")
class Listener {

    @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, Foo> record, @Payload Foo foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
        System.out.println(record);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
```

and

> Foo [bar=bar]
>
> ConsumerRecord(topic = so59970536, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 2, CreateTime = 1580315933731, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 13, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = Foo [bar=bar])

Comment: The doc of KafkaHandler say: It is important to understand that when a message arrives, the method selection depends on the payload type. The type is matched with a single non-annotated parameter, or one that is annotated with @Payload.


If I use only the consumerRecord<String, ContractRequestDto> does the mapping will be ok ? I use it only to get the partition/offset informations.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked fine for me; maybe your DTO is in a different package?

Comment: `>I use it only to get the partition/offset informations.` OK, but the second parameter is redundant since you already have it in the `record.value()`.

Comment: I have multiple KafkaHandler, and I get randomly the error...
I added the entity in second to use the @Payload as asked in the doc.

Comment: Can you provide more details when you ask me if the DTO is in another package? Moreover, I trust "*"

Comment: Often users have DTOs in different packages `com.producer.Foo` and `com.consumer.Foo` (compatible at the JSON level, but in ndifferent packages). If that's the case, the deserializer needs type mapping. If the error is random, however, something odd is going on.

Comment: Ok, I use the same class for the dto. Without any @payload arg but only the consumerRecord, can you confirm me that the kafkaHandlers should work?

Comment: Hmm; no; that won't work - you can get the offset etc with `@Header(KafakHeaders.OFFSET) long offset`.

Comment: I have 2 class annotated with KafkaListeners, with kafkaHandlers. The 2 KafkaListeners consumes the same topic. Can it be linked ? I have added some logs in the method matchHandlerMethod of DelegatingInvocableHandler, and I have the impression that only the handlers of one listener are compared to the incoming payload type. (does it explain the random?)

Comment: Yes. You should use different topics for each type or add a default @KafkaHandler to each listener to discard the unknowns. Listeners are independent.